# Copy Cell and Move to Another Cell (Offset) - VBA BEGINNER

Tags: vba, excel

I have a column that has many blanks and entries. I want to take the entries (ignoring the blanks) and move them over to the right once and down twice replacing the contents. I have a feeling you would use the offset function, however I don't know how to write this in VBA. I've only used offset as a formula. Any help would be appreciated...

Comment: Have a go at using offset, there are plenty of tutorials for it out there. I don't think that you will need to ignore the blanks as they will just remain blank anyway but you can have a go at using an If statement for that. You will want to look at using a loop (again view some tutorials) and it is always best to set the value of the offset (`.value`) to the value of the original cell. I wont go further as to not confuse you too much but give it a go, show us what you have done and the community will be happy to help and provide a good explanation of the logic.

Comment: I have content next to the blanks that I can't overwrite. If I use the offset function for the entire column without considering the blanks, won't it overwrite the cells with blanks too?

Comment: Oh in the column you are moving the data to? Yeah it would. Like I said then, use IF. Look at a for each loop (for each cell in range) then you can ask `if cell.value <> "" then` or `if not isblank(cell) then` and perform the action only after that.

Comment: When using the macro recorder, set the reference to relative, that will give you some idea on how the offset works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you need to create a loop, that moves through all the values of your range. There many ways to create loops, but here is one example:

```
'find last row of range
lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

'Loops through the values from 2 to the last row of range
For x=2 to lastrow 

Next x
```

Then I recommend to loop through the range and check each cell value for your criteria using the IF function:

```
'Checks for blank value in column A. If not blank  
If Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" then
'Do Something
End IF
```

Now in order to copy all values in a new range, just set the values of the old and new cell equal:

```
'Moves value from column A to column B and two cells down
Cells(x+2, 2).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value
```

In summary your code would look something like this:

```
Sub MoveValue ()

lastrow = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count

For x=2 to lastrow 
    If Cells(x, 1).Value <> "" then
      Cells(x+2, 2).Value = Cells(x, 1).Value
    End IF
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: This was exactly what I was looking for. Thank you for breaking it down for me and explaining in detail.

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.

Answer (score 2):

here's a one liner:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(2, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-1]" '<--| change "A:A" to actual column index
```

or, should your "not blank" cells derive from formulas in the cells:

```
Range("A:A").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeFormulas).Offset(2, 1).FormulaR1C1 = "=R[-2]C[-1]"
```

Comment: I tried changing "A:A" to "A1" to apply this to column A.. however it did some crazy things to my spreadsheet. Also - it doesn't seem this code will ignore blank cells, correct?

Comment: if you need to act on column "A" then leave `Range("A:A")`!

Comment: @RS, did you get thorough it?

Comment: I get an error that says 'no cells found' if I leave it as "A:A"

Comment: wha't's the _real_ content of your "not blank" cells? I mean: are there formulas?

Comment: The blank cells don't have formulas.

Comment: I asked for _not blank_ cells since your interested in these latter. Anyhow I edited answer to account for the case _not blank_ cells should derive from formulas. let me know